# regex for folders starting with _

Tags: php, regex

hi I'm writing a script to loop through the current directory and list all sub directories
all is working fine but i can't get it to exclude folders starting with an _

```
<?php

$dir = __dir__;

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        echo("<ul>");
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' || $file == '^[_]*$' ) continue;
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            echo "<li> <a href='$file'>$file</a></li>";
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`substr`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like :

```
||  substr($file, 0, 1) === '_'
```

Comment: perfect thanks won't let me tick yet as you answered too quick

Comment: @MitchellBray: While both answers are perfectly fine, consider looking at the answer timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a regex, use `$file[0] == '_'` or `substr($file, 0, 1) == '_'`

If you *do* want a regex, you need to use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) to check: `preg_match('/^_/', $file)`

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you would like to use regexp, you should use regex functions, like preg_match: `preg_match('/^_/', $file)`; but as said by ThiefMaster, in this case a `$file[0] == '_'` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution is to use [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). The [GlobIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php) can help you out. Each item is an instance of [SplFileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php).

```
<?php

$dir = __DIR__ . '/[^_]*';
$iterator = new GlobIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

if (0 < $iterator->count()) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($iterator as $item) {
        if ($item->isDir()) {
            echo sprintf("<li>%s</li>\n", $item);
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```